# How can one implement a Compact Directed Acyclic Word Graph (CDAWG) in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, directed-acyclic-graphs

How would one implement [this data structure](http://www.i.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~takeda/papers/PSC01.pdf) in C? It is a structure similar to but twice as space-efficient as the DAWG, that is more efficient than the trie which only compresses prefixes.

Comment: This is a rather open-ended question, that seems to be asking someone to just implement the data structure (a rather specific, specialized one) for you. You might get a better response if you (a) describe the data structure and (b) show what work you have already done, or any ideas that you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see from this [paper](http://www.i.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~takeda/papers/PSC01.pdf)

It's a trie with suffix compression to reduce the final state changes for a match, since I'd worked on something similar that, I had also considered doing that to save space. This was the solution I had thought of for the data structure, I'm interested to see if there are other approaches:

```
struct cdawg
{
    int issuffix:1;
    int length:31;
    char *s; // suffix if issuffix == 1, else array of valid transition chars
    struct cdawg *trans; // array of next states based on the index of trans char in s, null if suffix
};
```